# doubly linked list in alloy

Tags: linked-list, doubly-linked-list, alloy

I was trying to reverse a doubly linked list in alloy, I created a signature for it. This is the signature

```
sig node{}


//define each field as disjoint subset of node
sig first extends node{}

sig last extends node{} 

sig element extends node{}


sig doublylinkedlist{
head:one first,  //define one head pointer
null:one last,  //define one null pointer
ele:set element, //elements of the linked list
links:ele->ele, //paths between elements of a linked list
headpoint:head->one ele, //head points to one element of linked list
nullpoint:ele->null //one element of linked list points to null
}{
no links & iden  // no self refrence
one nullpoint //only one element points to null
links=links + ~links    //elements can point to prev element
all e:ele | e.(^(links))=ele // elements are connected
all e:ele | one r:head, n:null | (r->e) in headpoint => (e->n) not in nullpoint     //element being pointed by head cannot point to null
all e:ele | #(e.(links))<3 and #((links).e)<3 //elements cannot have more than 3   indegree and more than 3 outdegree
all e:ele | one r:head | (r->e) in headpoint => #((links).e)=1 && #(e.(links))=1 //element being pointed by head has indegree and outdegree 1
all e:ele | one n:null | (e->n) in nullpoint => #((links).e)=1 && #(e.(links))=1 //element being pointing to null has indegree and outdegree 1
 }

pred reverse{
}

run reverse for 1 doublylinkedlist, exactly  4 element ,exactly 1 first,exactly 1 last,exactly 0 node
```

The problem is that it gives desired result when i run for exactly 8 elemnts. After that it shows instances where one element has more than 3 indegree and 3 outdegree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first impression is that this model is overly complex for this problem, and I'd strongly suggest rewriting instead of debugging it.

Here are some unrelated comments about your model

- instead of using `exactly 1` in a scope specification, you can use `one sig` in the corresponding sig declaration (e.g., `one sig first` instead of `exactly 1 first`;
- instead of using `exactly 0` in a scope specification, you can use `abstract sig` in the corresponding sig declaration (e.g., `abstract sig node` instead of `exactly 0 node`;
- I really don't see a good reason to make "first", "last", and "element" different types of nodes; I would rather use a single `node` signature instead;
- having both `head: one first` and `headpoint: head -> one ele` seems redundant.  If the intention is to have a single head node, you can simply say `head: one node`;
- similarly, using `one r: head` in one of your appended facts is also unnecessary, because you know that `head` is going to point to exactly one node (which in your model is always going to be the single atom of `first`), so `r` is always going to be that node.

I don't know if you have a strong reason to model your list this way.  My first approach would be something more in the object-oriented style, e.g.,

```
sig Node {
    next: lone Node, 
    prev: lone Node
}

sig DLinkedList {
    head: lone Node
}

...
```

If you want your nodes to exist independently of the doubly-linked list (i.e., have the `DLinkedList` sig contain all necessary relations defining it, which is btw absolutely fine), I would still not use special `first` and `last` subsigs.  Maybe something like

```
sig Node {}

sig DLinkedList {
    head: lone Node,
    tail: lone Node,
    nxt: Node -> lone Node,
    prv: Node -> lone Node,
    nodes: set Node
} {
    nodes = head.*nxt
    some nodes => one tail
    no ^nxt & iden // no cycles
    nxt = ~prv     // symetric   
    no prv[head]   // head has no prv
    no nxt[tail]   // tail has no nxt
    head.^nxt = Node.^nxt // all nodes in nxt are reachable from head
}

pred reverse[dl, dl': DLinkedList] {
    dl'.head = dl.tail
    dl'.tail = dl.head
    dl'.nxt = dl.prv
}

run {
    some dl, dl': DLinkedList | reverse[dl, dl']

    // don't create any other lists or nodes
    #DLinkedList = 2
    Node = DLinkedList.nodes
}
```

Comment: I am a beginner at alloy and don't much other than predicates.I ran your program and it shows that head and tail are the same node. Is it a valid instance of DLL?. Also I would like to write a model for reverse, but don't know where to start.How would I show that the instance displayed is a reversed LL.It would look the same as an instance of a normal LL in alloy. I would very much appreciate if you could point in the correct direction on where to start.

Comment: If the size of the list is 1, then it is a valid instance if both head and tail point to the same node.

Comment: I just edited my answer to include the `reverse` predicate. To write a predicate like that, you typically pass two arguments, one for input or pre-state (`dl` in my code above) and one for output or post-state (`dl'`).  The body is in this case pretty simple, just says that everything in `dl'` is inverse of `dl'.