# Insertion and deletion in linked lists in alloy

Tags: list, alloy

I had created a simple version of linked list using alloy . Now I want to create a linked list in which I could perform insertion and deletion. I have just begun coding in alloy. for now I am having trouble doing complex operations like using functions and utilities .  If I could get some examples of how I could use utilities and functions as well as how I could actually perform insertion and deletion in alloy . I'd appreciate your help.

```
sig node{}

sig linked
{
  ele:set node,
  link:ele->lone ele,   
  head:lone ele
}{
  node = ele
  all x:ele | x in head.*link && head not in x.link && #x.link <=1 
}

fact{
  all  l:linked| all  e:l.ele| e->e not  in l.link //no self loop
}

fact
{
  all  l:linked|no e : l.ele | (e  in e.^(l.link )) //acyclic
}

pred a (l:linked,x:node)
{
  x in l.ele    
}

run a for 6 node,1 linked
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is kind of confusing, it could be much simpler. I would do it like this

```
sig Node{
    next : lone Node
}

one sig Head in Node {}                     -- head node is still a node

fact{
    all n : Node | n not in n.^next         -- no cycles
    no next.Head                            -- no node points to Head
    all n : Node - Head | some next.n       -- for all other nodes, there has to be someone pointing to them
}

run {} for 10
```

This model is static, in order to make the model dynamic, you need to understand de concept of States. I recommend you'd read [Software Abstractions](http://softwareabstractions.org/), written by the author of Alloy. A dynamic approach for the linked list would be too complex for you to understand at this point, you should do some simpler exercise.

The basic idea of states is (exercise based on the [address book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Modeling_from_A_to_Z/Modeling_principles/A_is_for_Alloy_analyzer#Simple_model_of_the_address_book) example in the book):

static example:

```
sig State {}

abstract sig Target {}

sig Email extends Target {}

abstract sig Name extends Email {
    name : set State,
    addr : Target some -> State
}

sig Group, Alias extends Name {}

fact {
    all a : Alias | lone a.addr
    no n : Name | n in n.^addr
}

run {}
```

dynamic example, in the local state idiom (= a way to express the states, there is also a global state idiom and an event idiom). Take a look at the predicates

```
open util/ordering[State]
sig State {}

abstract sig Target {}

sig Email extends Target {}

abstract sig Name extends Email {
    name : set State,
    addr : Target -> State
}

sig Group, Alias extends Name {}

fact {
    all s : State {
        all a : Alias & name.s | lone a.addr.s
        no n : name.s | n in n.^(addr.s)
        addr.s in name.s -> Target
        addr.s :> Name in Name -> name.s
    }
}

run {} for 3 but exactly 1 State

-- adding a name n, for a given pre state s and post state s'
pred addName [n : Name, s,s' : State] {

    -- the name must not exist in the pre state
    n not in name.s    

    -- the relation names in the post state is what is was
    -- in the pre state in addition to the new name
    name.s' = name.s + n  

    -- the address relation stays the same    
    addr.s' = addr.s
}

run addName for 3 but 2 State

pred addTarget [n : Name, t : Target, s,s' : State] {
    t not in n.addr.s
    name.s' = name.s
    addr.s' = addr.s + n->t
}

run addTarget for 3 but 2 State
```

You can also take a look at the following [slides](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/tutorials/day-course/).

Comment: Thanks chritiano . found the book Software Abstractions. Giving priority to other tasks at hand right now. Will try it today or tomorrow.  Thanks a tonne :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make the model "dynamic" in order to model operations like insertion and deletion.  Look at this topic ([doubly-linked-list-in-alloy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651231/doubly-linked-list-in-alloy)) where I gave an answer on how to model the reverse operation for a doubly-linked list, and then let us know if that wasn't helpful enough.  The basic idea you'll see there is to create a predicate that takes arguments for both pre-state and post-state, and asserts how the two are related.  For example, your insertion predicate could look like

```
// l - list in the pre-state
// x - node to be inserted
// l' - list in the post-state
pred insert (l: linked, x: node, l': linked) {
  l'.ele = l.ele + x
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well. Just went through what I was doing last year in alloy.